# angular 5 Passing a variable or parameters to a service

Tags: angular

Hello thisis probably super easy but i been struggling for 2 days.
I want to pass a variable to my service from [(ngmodel)]
a string that changes everywhere in weather component.
when i Type any city.
and i tried everything i can think of but no sucess,
So how do i pass that ngmodel that changes with what city i type 
to the service url.
I have this get function url.
but whatever i tried i cant get variable to change?onli works if i hardcode a city..
like so
my service ts

```
public globalVar='berlin';

   return this.http
             .get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+'$globalVar'+'&APIkey=f0a4b73f313ac53530db02abf0781')
             .map((response: Response) => {
                 return <IPosts[]>response.json();
             })
             .catch(this.handleError);
     }
```

i tried this multiple times but whatever i put in 
angular refuse to make globalVar a variable and just shows
$globalVar + apikey=f0
etz
in consolelog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(ngModelChange)` event on your input field to set a value from the model to the service.

Example:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model" (ngModelChange)="setValue($event)">

@Component({...})
export class FooComponent {
    setValue(value: string) {
        this.myService.value = value;
    }
}
```

Also, you have a typo in your ES6 syntax in the service URL. Use template strings like so:

```
public myVariable = 'world';

// ...

`Hello ${myVariable}`
```

[Template literals documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: I tried everything but both answers suppose to work hard to pick.

Comment: The only thing it boiled down to was i had to separate everything in the url like so get(this.code+this.city+this.api) everything else like custom var in the url did not work. unfortunately

Comment: Try again, use the backticks like ````

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
  .get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q= `${globalVar}&APIkey=f0a4b73f313ac53530db02abf0250781`)
```